# Thinking Sphinx indexing with Spree:Product model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, spree

how can I index over a model, whihc is defined in Spree like Spree:Product?

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :products
```

does not work (uninitialized constant Product). What is the syntax for using Spree:Product model?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching quite some time I found the answer [here](http://rdoc.info/github/pat/thinking-sphinx). The syntax is

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define 'spree/product', :with => :active_record do
   ...
end
```